# Objective-C how to define macro based on string comparison result

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

I want to define a macro based on string comparison result. The way I tried that was not working.

```
#define APP_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER    [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]
#define APP_EXTENSION_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER  @"abcded"
#define RESULT strcmp(APP_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER, APP_EXTENSION_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)
#if $RESULT == 1
        #define TARGET_IS_EXTENSION
#endif
```

Basically I am trying to achieve based the defined macro my app will differentiate between the native app and app extension.

Comment: Remember that the preprocessor does string substitution, not function evaluation.

Comment: Ok, then what is the best way to achieve it?.

Comment: @loganathan It's simple, just stop using macros and use normal constants/functions/methods.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem with this code is that `#define` and `#if` are evaluated when the code is compiled, while Objective-C method calls and C functions like `strcmp` are evaluated when the code is executed. Which means that you can't conditionally `#define` something this way since the code won't be executed until later.

A second problem is that you can't use `strcmp` with `NSString`. You need to use `NSString` methods.

It's probably possible to construct a macro that would do the comparison you want, but it would  be simpler to use a C function.

Comment: Even am using NSString comparison the result always be zero since am not getting the correct result. I can go for C function but that is possible at run time. I want to get the result at compile time itself. In that case my problem will solve easily.

Comment: You can't get this result at compile time. The best you could do there is to create a macro that would contain code to execute at run time and return the result. If you want to use `TARGET_IS_EXTENSION` at compile time then you need to just `#define` it in the extension compiler flags or in a header file.

Comment: Actually i can't use the macro "TARGET_IS_EXTENSION" the reason is i am having my all common code in my shared embedded framework. Since that bundle id is different than compare to both app bundle id and app extension bundle id. Also, my header file also shared by both app and app extension. Since i can't define the macro in such a way

Comment: You can define the macro in Xcode, in the compiler flags for the extension target. Then it will exist in the extension only. It doesn't have to be in a header file. But you cannot use Objective-C to check the bundle ID at compile time.

Comment: You mean under custom compiler flags under Other C flags section?. Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if RESULT
```

not $ surely, looking at the rest it get very confusing. #define just does string substitution so RESULT will become the strcmp which makes no sense as strcmp is a runtime function not preprocessor function so how can you have #if strcmp.....